# 16.04 Akonadi for Kontact does not start

Tags: kde, mysql, akonadi, kontact

I upgraded from 12.04 to 16.04 in two steps today and the PIM tools, like Kontact, no longer work due to Akonadi/MySQL problems. `akonadictl start` gives this output/error:

```
edA-qa@silent-red:~/.local/share/akonadi$ search paths:  ("/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/bin", "/sbin", "/bin", "/usr/games", "/usr/local/games", "/snap/bin", "/usr/sbin", "/usr/local/sbin", "/usr/local/libexec", "/usr/libexec", "/opt/mysql/libexec", "/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin", "/opt/mysql/sbin")
Found mysql_install_db:  "/usr/bin/mysql_install_db"
Found mysqlcheck:  "/usr/bin/mysqlcheck"
Database process exited unexpectedly during initial connection!
executable: "/usr/sbin/mysqld-akonadi"
arguments: ("--defaults-file=/home/edA-qa/.local/share/akonadi/mysql.conf", "--datadir=/home/edA-qa/.local/share/akonadi/db_data/", "--socket=/tmp/akonadi-edA-qa.zTSKeT/mysql.socket")
stdout: ""
stderr: "mysqld: Error on realpath() on '/var/lib/mysql-files' (Error 2 - No such file or directory)\n2016-05-29T21:28:22.334244Z 0 [Warning] The syntax '--log_warnings/-W' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use '--log_error_verbosity' instead.\n2016-05-29T21:28:22.334305Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).\n2016-05-29T21:28:22.334359Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to access directory for --secure-file-priv. Please make sure that directory exists and is accessible by MySQL Server. Supplied value : /var/lib/mysql-files\n2016-05-29T21:28:22.334364Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting\n\n2016-05-29T21:28:22.334380Z 0 [Note] Binlog end\n"
exit code: 1
process error: "Unknown error"
terminating service threads
terminating connection threads
stopping db process
Failed to remove Unix socket
Failed to remove runtime connection config file
Application 'akonadiserver' exited normally...
```

There is no `/var/lib/mysql-files` directory, but I'm not sure why it is looking for one. There is `/var/lib/mysql` directory, but shouldn't it be using the mysql setup in the `.local/share/akonadi`?

How can I fix this (preferably without losing my calendar information)?

Comment: My quick solution is to just delete `.local/share/akonadi`. I realize my calendar information is just inside ICS files anyway and I don't use the MySQL DB at all.